# get a single value from the database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i always use this ugly code to get a single value from the database for a given id

for example here i want to get the number of visits for a website

```
// ============================================ getNumberOfVisits()
//  
//  website_name : ..
//  return the number of visits for a given website
//
private function getNumberOfVisits($website_name)
{
    $visits = Website::where('name', $website_name)->get(['number_of_visit']);
    return $visits[0]['attributes']['number_of_visit'];
}
```

is there another way to get a single value from the database for a particular column given a where statement?

Comment: why do you need another way? is this bad?

Comment: no, it's just too long, and i was wondering that it may be a better way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$website = Website::where('name', $website_name)->first(['number_of_visit']);
return $website->number_of_visit;
```

Or even better:

```
$visits = Website::where('name', $website_name)->pluck('number_of_visit');
```

#### In case you want to know...

`pluck()` actually does the same as my first code example. Here's the source:

```
public function pluck($column)
{
    $result = $this->first(array($column));

    if ($result) return $result->{$column};
}
```

Comment: Well I like it more than something like `getSingleValueFromFirstResult` ;)